# Alternatives to Python beautiful soup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wrote a few lines to get data from a financial data website.

It simply uses `beautiful soup` to parse and `requests` to get.

Is there any other simpler or sleeker ways of getting the same result?

I'm just after a discussion to see what others have come up with.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import bs4
import requests


def get_webpage():
    symbols = ('ULVR','AZN','HSBC')
    for ii in symbols:
        url = 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + ii + '.L/history?p=' + ii + '.L'
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        rows = soup.find_all('tr')
        data = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].find_all('td')] for i in range(len(rows))]


        #for i in data:
        # [-7:] Date
        # [-6:] Open
        # [-5:] High
        # [-4:] Low
        # [-3:] Close
        # [-2:] Adj Close
        # [-1:] Volume

        data = DataFrame(data)

        print(ii, data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_webpage()
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried yfinance or yahoo-finance libraries? not sure if they work on uk finance but those are pretty flexible if it's reglar NYSE, NASDAQ symbols

Comment: Cheers @JonathanLeon, I've worked with it a bit in the past but they seem slightly cumbersome for my kneeds

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `read_html()` method:

```
symbols = ('ULVR','AZN','HSBC')
df=[pd.read_html('https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + ii + '.L/history?p=' + ii + '.L') for ii in symbols]
df1=df[0][0]
df2=df[1][0]
df3=df[2][0]
```

Comment: Thats pretty neat @anuragdabas, i've added an extra cool part for slicing

Answer (score 0):

As its just the entire table that I want, it seems easier to use `pandas.read_html`, especially as I have no need to scrape anything in particular apart from the entire table.

There is some helpful information on this site as a guidance https://pbpython.com/pandas-html-table.html

By just using `import pandas as pd` I get the result I am after.

```
   import pandas as pd

   def get_table()
 
        symbols = ('ULVR','AZN','HSBC')
        position=0
        for ii in symbols:
            table=[pd.read_html('https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + ii + '.L/history? 
            p=' + ii + '.L')]

            print (symbols[position])
            print (table, '\n')
        
            position += 1

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        get_table()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.